# Another AS3 Bubbling or Capturing

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created an events class to handle custom events and Im currently playing around with some tests...

```
    public function CommenerB():void {

            stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, function(e:Event) {
                dispatchEvent(new NEvents(NEvents.STAGE_RESIZE));
            });

            addEventListener(NEvents.STAGE_RESIZE, function(e:NEvents) {
                trace("crayon");    
                dispatchEvent(new NEvents(NEvents.STAGE_RESIZE_PUSH));
            });

            var mc:Sprite = new Sprite();
            addChild(mc);
            mc.addEventListener(NEvents.STAGE_RESIZE_PUSH, function(h:NEvents) {
                trace("palum");
            });
    }
```

My problem is that "palum" never gets traced even when "crayon" does, showing the event is dispatched but not continued to its own child mc. Why is that...thought the capturing phases of as3 went from stage > timeline > child...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event capture phase will only propagate down to the event target (the object that dispatched the event) and then bubble back up to the root.

Since your `mc` sprite does not appear to be part of the propagation chain, its event listener will never get called.

Comment: Erm...ok. Thanks for the reply. Since the mc in question is a child of the said root, shouldn't it actually be part of the propagation chain as the parent > child concept assumes? And if not, then what do I need to do to make it part of it? Thanks

Comment: I'm just fully understanding what you're saying. What you're basically saying is that the parent, in this case root, isn't broadcasting downwards beyond itself and thus mc can listen for the broadcast...but how then is the stage broadcasting downwards using similar calls? (stage > root > children) so how can I get the broadcast to get to the mc?